# Type error is occured while i am compiling

Tags: python-3.x

while i am compiling i am getting this error.I have already searched but no solution is not working

```
import requests
import tqdm

BASE_URL="http://www.buzzfeed.com/api/v2/feeds/index"


with open("G:\clickbait-detector-master\data/clickbait.txt", "a+") as outfile:

    for page in tqdm.tqdm(range(0, 30)):
        response = requests.get(BASE_URL, { "p": page }).json()
        titles = [each["title"].encode("ascii", "ignore") for each in response["buzzes"]]
        outfile.write("\n" + "\n".join(titles))
```

I am getting output after compiling

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-5231e1171fef> in <module>()
     11         response = requests.get(BASE_URL, { b"p": page }).json()
     12         titles = [each["title"].encode("ascii", "ignore") for each in response["buzzes"]]
---> 13         outfile.write("\n" + "\n".join(titles))

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `each["title"].encode("ascii", "ignore")` you're producing a list of objects of type `bytes`, and here `"\n".join(titles)` you're trying to `join` them on a `str`ing. It's not possible to concatenate a `bytes` object and a string, so you get an error.

If you'd like to produce a `bytes` object after `joining, do this:

```
"\n".join(titles)
```

But then you'd need to open your file in binary mode. Otherwise, just don't `encode` your data.